# ComboBox with ItemTemplate that includes a button

Tags: wpf, silverlight, combobox, itemtemplate

So, lets say I have a ComboBox with a custom data template.  One of the items in the data template is a button:

```
<ComboBox Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="ClickMe" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

The problem with this is that the button eats the click, and the item does not get selected if the button is selected.  This means that the pull-down does not go away, and no item is selected.

I get WHY this is happening.

Is there a way to work around it?  Possibly a way to process the button click (I am binding to a command) and tell it to continue up the chain so the combo box can also process the click?

Note: I am seeing my problem in Silverlight, but I am guessing that the exact same behavior can be seen with WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to set the SelectedItem in the button's command.

Comment: Yeah, I considered that, but doing that does not dismiss the pull-down that the Combo Box creates.

Comment: There is also an IsOpen (or something very similar) property on ComboBoxes, you can set it to False. You might also be able to set Focusable="False" on the buttons and get it to happen automagically.

Comment: Yeah, it ended up being a combination of the two.  See my answer for a full solution, but I want to give you the cred points, so I am marking your answer as correct.

Answer (score 8):

OK, I got it figured out.  It is a total hack, but it still lets me bind my command to the button and continue to have Combo-box behavior for selecting the item:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="MyCombo" Width="150" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="ClickMe" Click="Button_Click" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And in the code behind:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyCombo.SelectedItem = (sender as Button).DataContext;
    MyCombo.IsDropDownOpen = false;
}
```

If I really wanted to, I could bind the SelectedItem and IsDropDownOpen to properties in my ViewModel but I decided against it to keep this behavior as a hack extension of the XAML, in an effort to keep my ViewModel clean.

Answer (score 1):

I found another possibility for the MVVM context. I used an derived class for `ComboBox` and if an item is adden which derives from `ButtonBase` I attach to the `Click` event to close the `ComboBox`.

This works for my project - but just, because the items itself are buttons, it would not work if they just contain buttons as a child element.

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        // use Loaded event to modify inital items.
        Loaded += OnLoaded;
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
    {
        if (Items != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in Items)
            {
                var button = item as ButtonBase;
                if (button != null)
                {
                    ModifyButtonItem(button);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnItemsChanged(System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);
        // Check added items. If an item is a button, modify the button.
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                var button = item as ButtonBase;
                if (button != null)
                {
                    ModifyButtonItem(button);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void ModifyButtonItem(ButtonBase button)
    {
        button.Click += (sender, args) => { IsDropDownOpen = false; };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a way to do what you want. If you were to put a `Button` in a `ListBox`, for example, the same behavior occurs - clicking the `Button` does not cause its item in the `ListBox` to be selected. In fact, this is the case for any control in an `ItemsControl` that supports selection.

You might be able to do something with the `Click` event and mark it as not handled so that it continues up the visual tree, but even then I'm not sure if that would work or not.